# Visual Studio edit label text shortcut

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, shortcut

Is there a shortcut in Visual Studio 2010 to jump into the Properties - Text field of the current selected item?

EDIT: Thank you Steve :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your current keyboard layout, but if you press two times the key F4 with layout Visual C#2005 you get the editing inside the text property of the current label